# Reading file of Airport codes and lat, long coordinates

Tags: file-io, hashmap, treeset

I have been given a file of 1200 airports that lists airport code, latitude, longitude, city, and state.

EX: ANB 33.58 85.85 Anniston AL

Eventually I will be writing methods 'Distance' to return distance and information of two input airports, 'Closest' to return code and distance of closest airports to and input airport, and 'Shortest' to find shortest trip that begins and input airport and travels to n airports.

For now my question is, what is the best way to read in this data that will eventually make it easier for me to write/calculate distances later?

Such as would I read in the file then put in a HashMap, or TreeSet in one method, and how would this be done? or would I wait and use HashMap/TreeSet in the other methods?

Sorry I don't have any code yet but I'm stuck on this for now and you guys all ways help me out tremendously, so just looking for direction at this point.

Comment: Have you looked at GeoHashing?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the simplest approach would be to create an object to store the information for one airport and then store all of those objects in one array.  I say this because you're probably going to be doing a lot of iteration over the entire array in order to build your other methods, and since you *only* have 1200 objects, any fancy sorting isn't going to speed up your program that much.

I suppose you could also divide your set of airports into geographic regions and override `hashcode()` in order to group nearby airports together, but that doesn't buy you much speed, and it's not particularly helpful for airports near the edge of a region.  Similarly, you could implement a [GeoHash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash), but these also have issues with certain edge conditions that may or may not matter with your set of airports.  (There are also open source Java implementations of GeoHashes out there if you do a search.)

Whatever you do, don't set up a group of `HashMaps` to map airport name to each of your other pieces of data.  That is a common beginner approach, but it is also the slowest approach.  Creating an object is much better.